# Reinterpretation of fuzzy number

Tags: algorithm, fuzzy

I have a fuzzy number of "being about 20 years old", e.g., with these values of `[age, degree]`: `[10, 0], [15, 0.5], [20, 1], [25, 0.6], [30, 0.3], [35, 0])`

The degree to which a number is consider about 20 is zero for ages `<= 10` or `>= 35`.

It rises or falls linearly between the various ages to reach the target (such as `0.5` at age `15`, a step of `0.1` per year).

How can I calculated degrees of "being **at least** 20 years old"? Can I just sum the the degrees from the original number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I wouldn't be summing those degrees. While "is *about* 20 years old" may be fuzzy, "is at *least* 20 years old" is *not.*

As those tuples represent how "about 20 years old" an age is, with the "about-ness" varying linearly between the data points, that means you have something like:

| Age | about-ness |
| --- | --- |
| <=10 | 0% |
| 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 | 10, 20, 30, 40, 50% (0 to 0.5 in 5 steps) |
| 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 | 60, 70, 80, 90, 100% (0.5 to 1.0 in 5 steps) |
| 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 | 92, 84, 76, 68, 60% (1.0 to 0.6 in 5 steps) |
| 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 | 54, 48, 42, 36, 30% (0.6 to 0.3 in 5 steps) |
| 31, 32, 33, 34, 35 | 24, 18, 12, 6, 0% (0.3 to 0.0 in 5 steps) |
| >35 | 0% |

That means the "is at least 20 years old" can be represented very succinctly as `[19,0], [20, 1], [999_999, 1]`.

In other words, anything 19 or less is "100% no", from 20 to a ridiculously old age is "100% yes" with no gradual increase or decline. If the final "about-ness" just maintained the last value up to infinity, you could even get rid of that large age knowing that `[20, 1]` would carry forward forever.

---

If you instead wanted the criteria to be "is about 20 years old but definitely at least 20" (something once again fuzzy), you could just use `([19, 0], [20, 1], [25, 0.6], [30, 0.3], [35, 0])`, getting rid of the possibility that any item under 20 could qualify.

---

If you wanted the criteria to be "is at least about 20 years old", that would involve keeping the fuzziness below the age but ensuring it stays at 100% above, such as `[10, 0.0], [15, 0.5], [20, 1.0], [999_999, 1.0]`.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for very fast answer!

Yes, you understood the meaning correctly; sorry for not detailed description. However, I'm confused about the "100% no" / "100% yes" and "being at least 20 ... not being fuzzy". This would hold if I knew the age (crisp value). However, my age is defined as fuzzy (e.g., somebody has the degree of 0.5 being 15 years), so I'm not sure that he/she is not 15. How can I then by 100 % sure that he/she is below 20?

Comment: No probs, @Mike.sof: Re your comment "Yes, you understood the meaning correctly", I've edited your question slightly to make that clear, and assist any others that may also wish to answer.

Comment: @Mike.sof, that's a different test: the fuzzy "is at least *about* 20 years old", rather than the non-fuzzy "is at least 20 years old". I've added a section at the end to address that possibility.